# I need to put the data from the diagram in 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization, erd

[image: employee assignment to company projects]

This is a simple list table of a company trying to keep track of employee assignment to company projects (in other words, not a database but a flat one table file).

You will design a database for this company so that they won’t be relying on a simple 1 table list system to keep track of their data. Looking at the table below, identify the separate entities and attributes and design a logical level Entity Relationship Diagram for this company.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Homework is **not** off-topic here but there are two conditions: 1st is that you tell us it's homework and 2nd is that you've made some effort yourself ("I looked at site X and it says Y so I did A, B and C..."). Neither of these two conditions have been met, so I'm afraid that I'm going to have to VtC. There are some articles on my profile about how to ask questions here - you might want to have a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 2):

To satisfy a 3NF normalization you also needs to satisfy the 1NF and 2NF normalization.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_3NF

Here's a help on the way with the tables and fields.

```
Assignment
    ProjectCode
    EmployeeNo
    DepartmentNo

Project
    ProjectCode
    ProjectName
    ProjectManager
    ProjectBudget

Employee  
    EmployeeNo  
    EmployeeName  
    HourlyRate

Department
    DepartmentNo
    DepartmentName
```

You have to design the ERD yourself.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Download a software like [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) to help you draw the ERD.